# Can I implement a role based access to menu items in content creation?

Tags: routes

Example:

role A is authorized to publish under specific taxonomy terms. When he activates "provide a   menu link" I would like to restrict the parent items available to certain menus. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can u explain a bit more. I find it hard to help you with the above description.